# need help on this toggle for little change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

in this code below i simply want when i click on any content inside panel (content contained in p tags within panel), should not slidup the panel, till the click on panel or elsewhere is used but not child elements p inside panels, see html in fiddle for help and click try should not close the panel if the click event on other than it is used. this script was helped me with mr praveen earlier.

the code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle li > .panel").hide();
    $('.plusminus').html('+');

    $('#toggle li').click(function () {
        if( !$(this).children('.panel').is(":visible") ) {
            $("#toggle li > .panel").slideUp();
            $('.plusminus').html('+');
        }
        a = $(this).children(".plusminus");
        $(this).children(".panel").slideToggle('fast', function(){
            a.html($(this).is(":visible") ? '--' : '+');
        });
    });

    $("body").click(function(event){
        if ($(event.target).closest("ul").attr('id') != "toggle") {
            $("#toggle li > .panel").slideUp();
            $('.plusminus').html('+');
        }
    });
});
```

fiddle to play with is

http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/Ss3xU/26/

Comment: I don't really understand your question. "can i get it working that if i click on any content tags withing panels"? What do you mean by content tags exactly? Which objects on your page are supposed to be clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `$("#toggle li > .panel").hide();` on `document load` to make the panels open on `load`

add `$("#toggle li > .panel").click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });`
will make the dropdown not to close when you click inside the panel

Comment: @ Nisanth:+1. @Kamal: Btw, Do you really want to collapse one menu on opening other, or is it an issue?

Comment: @Nisanth see in the html in fiddel click on (try), that should not slideup until click event on elesewhere other than on it is executed.

Comment: @Nisanth many thanx it has worked, my goodness i didn't occure to me, you guys are really a great help for a newbie like me...